# Como fazer o retorno de uma função javascript retornar um HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tirei a seguinte função em JavaScript (jQuery):

```
      function CustomAlert() {
            this.show = function (nome) {


            };

        }
        var Alert = new CustomAlert();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            Alert.show('meu nome e hugo');
        });
```

Como faço para ela retornar, escrever a tela o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="nome">meu nome e hugo</div>
```

Comment: A tua pergunta não é clara... queres criar uma função de nome `Alert` (com a primeira letra grande) e fazer ela escrever no HTML? Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer, como chamas a função e o HTML que tens?

Comment: @Sergio Ok, me desculpa. editei minha pergunta, da uma olhada agora por favor.

Comment: Tenta: `document.getElementsByClassName("nome")[0].innerHTML  = 'Meu Nome é Hugo';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta direcionar a mensagem usando um dos seguintes códigos Jquery, ambas funcionam porém com uma leve diferença veja:

```
$("div.nome").html('meu nome é <b>hugo</b>');//a tag <b> é renderizada
```

Também pode ser usado com o "text":

```
$("div.nome").text('meu nome é <b>hugo</b>');//a tag <b> é string e não renderiza.
```

Mais informações você encontra nos links abaixo:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Boa sorte!